# Delimited File with Varying Number of Rows Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a delimited file separated by hashes that looks somewhat like this,

value#value#value#value#value#value##value

value#value#value#value##value#####value#####value

value#value#value#value###value#value####value##value

As you can see, when separated by hashes, there are more columns in the 2nd and 3rd rows than there is in the first. I want to be able to ingest this into a database using a ADF Data Flow after some transformations. However, whenever I try to do any kind of mapping, I always only see 7 columns (the number of columns in the first row).

Is there any way to get all of the values? As many columns as there are in the row with most number of items? I do not mind the nulls.

Note: I do not have a header row for this.

Comment: Could you try to have the sample file with all the number of columns and import the schema.

Comment: This is a good method. I actually converted the file to a csv using pandas in an Azure Function and then triggered the pipeline. With this, we can actually avoid the Function, yes?

Comment: please accept the below answer if it suffices your question so that the question will stand as answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Data Factory directly will not be able to Import schema -row with the maximum number of column. Hence, it is important to make sure you have same number of columns in your file.

You can use Azure functions to validate your file and update it to get equal number of columns in all rows.

You could give it a try to have a local file with row with the maximum number of column and import the schema from the file, else you have to go for Azure Functions where you have to convert the file and then trigger the pipeline.